# How exactly does a point-contact razor blade diode work?

Tags: diodes, radio

The original foxhole radio used a razor blade with an oxide layer and a makeshift cats whisker to form a diode.  How exactly did this makeshift diode work?  Is it actually a P/N junction, or does it work through some other principal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s-whisker_detector [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @Transistor That just says something like metal oxides have semiconductor properties - pretty unsatisfying.

Comment: It's actually an interesting question if this is a junction between two semiconductors, or between a semiconductor and a metal that might be considered a primitive Schottky diode, ie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier   Given the need to manually adjust in search of a region and contact pressure with the right properties, it's even possible the answer is not consistent.

Comment: @Transistor The most specific that page gets, unless I'm missing something, is "The oxide layers that form on many ordinary metal surfaces have semiconducting properties[...]"  Even its reference doesn't go much further in reference to that kind of material.  I was hoping for something a bit more specific.  So, can I assume that the whisker is the P-type conductor and the oxide layer is the N-type conductor and together can form a poor diode?  But like Christ Stratton suggests, I had a feeling the answer might not have necessarily been that simple, especially since the whisker material varies.

Comment: @Ravenstine: Sorry if I brusque. Your question is actually more nuanced than many of the "please do a web search for me or write me an article to save me looking it up" type of questions and I didn't pick up on it. I think Chris is doing a good job below.

Comment: Anyone want to tackle explaining the graphite pencil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried in the [Wikipedia Article on Crystal Radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) is an asseration that a cat's whisker detector is a form of [Schottky Barrier Diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier) formed by the junction between a metal and a metal oxide semiconductor.  This would be in contrast to an "ordinary" diode formed by the junction between two semiconductors being relatively P-type vs N-type with respect to one another.

However, there was a lot of variation in materials used, and getting satisfactory results seemed to require a lot of manual adjustment to find a region with the right properties and suitable contact pressure, so it is at least worth considering if more than one phenomenon has been utilized - one might ask if there might also have been junctions between regions of different oxidation states, for example.

A contrasting explanation is that of a point contact diode, where the migration of metal from the contact wire into the semiconductor serves to locally dope a region to differing properties than the surrounding bulk - apparently this is done in manufacturing by passing a large current through it to cause migration, so it's an interesting question if anyone ever "primed" their cat's whisker setup with a few electrochemical battery cells.  [Jeri Ellsworth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmotkjMSKnI) electro-forms such doped regions around a phosphor broze wire by discharging a capacitor through a resistor.

It so happens that if you want to make a crystal-radio like device today (or a diode power detector for measuring RF) a modern packaged Schottky Diode is a frequent choice, typically having a low forward voltage and often being more available and cheaper than a Germanium Diode.